# How to accept cookies using selenium for python?

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, cookies, automation

I am trying to automate Facebook, but I can't get passed ''Accept Cookies'' alert. I am using selenium for python. I tried every possible solution I could find on the internet. Does somebody have an idea what can I do for this to work ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

[Here are all the ''solutions'' I tried so far and none of these worked for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwa5c.png)

Comment: Just so you know. Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So don't be surprised if your account gets banned. Instead use their API.

Comment: please paste your code as text here and not an image